# Need a GPath query to find max date + a string field

Tags: java, groovy

Need a way to search for an entry w/ the maximum Date + Value == "001"

If I do this to find an entry w/ the max Date + Value == "001", it doesn't work. Is there a way to do the combined query?

```
def xmls = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File("C:/file.xml"));
Object oTest = xmls.Test.Entry.find{ v -> v.Value == "001" }.max{ d -> 
Date.parse('MM/dd/yyyy', d.Date.toString())
```

Input xml example:

```
<Test>
<Entry>
   <Date>01/12/2017</Date>
   <Value>001</Value>
</Entry>
<Entry>
   <Date>02/15/2017</Date>
   <Value>001</Value>
</Entry>
<Entry>
   <Date>03/15/2017</Date>
   <Value>002</Value>
</Entry>
</Test>
```

Output I need is:

```
Date>02/15/2017</Date>
<Value>001</Value>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def xmls = new XmlSlurper().parseText('''<Test>
<Entry>
   <Date>01/12/2017</Date>
   <Value>001</Value>
</Entry>
<Entry>
   <Date>02/15/2017</Date>
   <Value>001</Value>
</Entry>
<Entry>
   <Date>03/15/2017</Date>
   <Value>002</Value>
</Entry>
</Test>''');

Object oTest = xmls.Entry.findAll{ v -> v.Value == "001" }.max{ d -> Date.parse('MM/dd/yyyy', d.Date.toString()) }
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(oTest)
```

result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Entry>
  <Date>02/15/2017</Date>
  <Value>001</Value>
</Entry>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! It makes complete sense. I needed to do the FindAll first then apply the max closure. Thanks again.